# Federated Results Web Part is not visible

Tags: search, enterprise-search

I installed Bing search provider to our SharePoint 2010 server. Now I am trying to embed the search results coming from Bing to search results page but Federated Results Web part is not visible in the Search category in web part list.

I deactivated and reactivated SharePoint Search Web Parts feature to no avail, the web part is not visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: check if you got any errors using ULS log and also check if webpart is being added to page or not, by using "?contents=1" at end of URL.

Comment: My problem is there is not a web part named Federated Results in the list of insertable web parts so I can't add it to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the guide outlined by microsoft?

> 1.Download the Open Search Description (.OSDX) file. You can download a connector from the Available connectors list.
>
> 2.Import the file into the search solution by doing the following: In Central Administration, click Manage service applications, and then
> click either the name of the Search service application (when you use
> SharePoint Server 2010, Search Server 2010, or Search Server 2010
> Express) or the name of your FAST Search Query Search Service
> Application (when you use FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint)
> where you want to add the federated location.
>
> On the Search
> Administration page, click Federated Locations, and then click Import
> Location.
>
> On the Import Federated Location page, browse to the .OSDX
> file that you saved in step 1, select the file, and then click Open.
> Click OK, and then click Done.
>
> 3.Connect the federated location to an end-user results page by doing the following: On a results page in the Search Center, on the Site
> Actions menu, click Edit Page. Click the zone where you want to add
> the Web Part, and then add the Federated Results Web Part, Top
> Federated Results Web Part, or Core Results Web Part to the page.
>
> Right-click the Web Part, and then click Properties.
>
> In the Web Part
> Properties panel, expand Location Properties, on the Location
> drop-down list, select the location that you imported, and then click
> OK. On the ribbon, click Stop Editing.

If you do not see the web part then you need to go to Site Collection Features to activate it ;)

go to Site Actions->Site Settings-> Go to top level site settings->Site collection features and Activate the Office SharePoint Server Search Web Parts feature.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint//ff727944.aspx

hope it helps :)